# Change title of combobox JAVA

Tags: java, combobox

Hi i would like to change the titel of my combobox so when the application starts it should say something like choose.... Right now it just shows the diffrent types of Strings i gave it.

```
String[] KundLista = { "Normal", "Företag", "Student"};
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(KundLista);
    comboBox.setToolTipText("Välj vilken typ av Kund du är");       
    comboBox.setBounds(171, 46, 97, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

![]Pic of the Frame[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43nrr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve this. Here is one example:

```
class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
        private String title;

        public MyComboBoxRenderer(String newTitle) {
            title = newTitle;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (index == -1 && value == null) setText(title );
            else setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }
}
```

Once you created MyComboBoxRenderer class, you can edit your code into this:

```
String[] KundLista = { "Normal", "Företag", "Student"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(KundLista);
comboBox.setToolTipText("Välj vilken typ av Kund du är"); 
combobox.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer("Choose"));  
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1); // By default it selects first item, we don't want any selection  
comboBox.setBounds(171, 46, 97, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
```

Comment: The Settext and return this gives me errors.



Error for setText " The method setText(String) is undefined for the type MyComboBoxRenderer"

Error for return this "Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyComboBoxRenderer to Component "

Comment: Does your MyComboBoxRenderer class extends JLabel ?

Comment: If this answer has helped you solve your problem, please accept it. :)